# Spark SQL window function with complex condition

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

This is probably easiest to explain through example.  Suppose I have a DataFrame of user logins to a website, for instance:

```
scala> df.show(5)
+----------------+----------+
|       user_name|login_date|
+----------------+----------+
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-04|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-04|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-06|
|  OprahWinfreyJr|2012-01-10|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-11|
+----------------+----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

I would like to add to this a column indicating when they became an active user on the site.  But there is one caveat: there is a time period during which a user is considered active, and after this period, if they log in again, their `became_active` date resets.  Suppose this period is **5 days**.  Then the desired table derived from the above table would be something like this:

```
+----------------+----------+-------------+
|       user_name|login_date|became_active|
+----------------+----------+-------------+
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-04|   2012-01-04|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-04|   2012-01-04|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-06|   2012-01-04|
|  OprahWinfreyJr|2012-01-10|   2012-01-10|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-11|   2012-01-11|
+----------------+----------+-------------+
```

So, in particular, SirChillingtonIV's `became_active` date was reset because their second login came after the active period expired, but Booooooo99900098's `became_active` date was not reset the second time he/she logged in, because it fell within the active period.

My initial thought was to use window functions with `lag`, and then using the `lag`ged values to fill the `became_active` column; for instance, something starting roughly like:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val window = Window.partitionBy("user_name").orderBy("login_date")
val df2 = df.withColumn("tmp", lag("login_date", 1).over(window))
```

Then, the rule to fill in the `became_active` date would be, if `tmp` is `null` (i.e., if it's the first ever login) or if `login_date - tmp >= 5` then `became_active = login_date`; otherwise, go to the next most recent value in `tmp` and apply the same rule.  This suggests a recursive approach, which I'm having trouble imagining a way to implement.

My questions: Is this a viable approach, and if so, how can I "go back" and look at earlier values of `tmp` until I find one where I stop?  I can't, to my knowledge, iterate through values of a Spark SQL `Column`.  Is there another way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.2**

Recent Spark releases provide native support for session windows in both batch and structured streaming queries (see [SPARK-10816](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10816) and its sub-tasks, especially [SPARK-34893](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34893)).

The official documentation provides nice [usage example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39542bb81f8570219770bb6533c077f44f6cbd2a/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredSessionization.scala#L66-L105).

**Spark < 3.2**

Here is the trick. Import a bunch of functions:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, datediff, lag, lit, min, sum}
```

Define windows:

```scala
val userWindow = Window.partitionBy("user_name").orderBy("login_date")
val userSessionWindow = Window.partitionBy("user_name", "session")
```

Find the points where new sessions starts:

```scala
val newSession =  (coalesce(
  datediff($"login_date", lag($"login_date", 1).over(userWindow)),
  lit(0)
) > 5).cast("bigint")

val sessionized = df.withColumn("session", sum(newSession).over(userWindow))
```

Find the earliest date per session:

```scala
val result = sessionized
  .withColumn("became_active", min($"login_date").over(userSessionWindow))
  .drop("session")
```

With dataset defined as:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("SirChillingtonIV", "2012-01-04"), ("Booooooo99900098", "2012-01-04"),
  ("Booooooo99900098", "2012-01-06"), ("OprahWinfreyJr", "2012-01-10"), 
  ("SirChillingtonIV", "2012-01-11"), ("SirChillingtonIV", "2012-01-14"),
  ("SirChillingtonIV", "2012-08-11")
).toDF("user_name", "login_date")
```

The result is:

```
+----------------+----------+-------------+
|       user_name|login_date|became_active|
+----------------+----------+-------------+
|  OprahWinfreyJr|2012-01-10|   2012-01-10|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-04|   2012-01-04| <- The first session for user
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-11|   2012-01-11| <- The second session for user
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-14|   2012-01-11| 
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-08-11|   2012-08-11| <- The third session for user
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-04|   2012-01-04|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-06|   2012-01-04|
+----------------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but can you help me understand the coalesce part of the solution??

Comment: @SanchitGrover If `datediff($"login_date", lag($"login_date", 1).over(userWindow))` evaluates to `null` (first row in the frame) get 0.

Comment: Then how this ```val sessionized = df.withColumn("session", sum(newSession).over(userWindow))``` is increasing the count?

Comment: It is a cumulative sum of values in set {0, 1}.

Answer (score 6):

Refactoring [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42449617)  to work with `Pyspark`

In `Pyspark` you can do like below.

`create data frame`

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[
("SirChillingtonIV", "2012-01-04"), 
("Booooooo99900098", "2012-01-04"), 
("Booooooo99900098", "2012-01-06"), 
("OprahWinfreyJr", "2012-01-10"), 
("SirChillingtonIV", "2012-01-11"), 
("SirChillingtonIV", "2012-01-14"), 
("SirChillingtonIV", "2012-08-11")
], 
("user_name", "login_date"))
```

The above code creates a data frame like below

```
+----------------+----------+
|       user_name|login_date|
+----------------+----------+
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-04|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-04|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-06|
|  OprahWinfreyJr|2012-01-10|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-11|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-14|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-08-11|
+----------------+----------+
```

Now we want to first find out the difference between `login_date` is more than `5` days.

For this do like below.

Necessary imports

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window


# defining window partitions  
login_window = Window.partitionBy("user_name").orderBy("login_date")
session_window = Window.partitionBy("user_name", "session")

session_df = df.withColumn("session", f.sum((f.coalesce(f.datediff("login_date", f.lag("login_date", 1).over(login_window)), f.lit(0)) > 5).cast("int")).over(login_window))
```

When we run the above line of code if the `date_diff` is `NULL` then the `coalesce` function will replace `NULL` to `0`.

```
+----------------+----------+-------+
|       user_name|login_date|session|
+----------------+----------+-------+
|  OprahWinfreyJr|2012-01-10|      0|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-04|      0|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-11|      1|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-14|      1|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-08-11|      2|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-04|      0|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-06|      0|
+----------------+----------+-------+


# add became_active column by finding the `min login_date` for each window partitionBy `user_name` and `session` created in above step
final_df = session_df.withColumn("became_active", f.min("login_date").over(session_window)).drop("session")

+----------------+----------+-------------+
|       user_name|login_date|became_active|
+----------------+----------+-------------+
|  OprahWinfreyJr|2012-01-10|   2012-01-10|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-04|   2012-01-04|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-11|   2012-01-11|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-01-14|   2012-01-11|
|SirChillingtonIV|2012-08-11|   2012-08-11|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-04|   2012-01-04|
|Booooooo99900098|2012-01-06|   2012-01-04|
+----------------+----------+-------------+
```