# How to compute start and end times of user sessions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a recommended way to do the following type of transform:
Input:

```
userID  timestamp  action  
u1      100        edit1
u1      122        edit2
u1      135        edit3
u2      143        edit4
u2      158        edit5
u1      212        edit6
u1      241        edit7
```

Output:

```
userID  startTime  endTime  actions
u1      100        135      [edit1, edit2, edit3]
u2      143        158      [edit4, edit5]
u1      212        241      [edit6, edit7]
```

Grouping by userID results in the session information being lost. Same with using Window functions.

EDIT for clarity:
In this case, note that user u1 appears 2 times in the result set. The user u2's actions break up u1's actions into two sessions.

Comment: Thanks @jaceklaskowski. The other question helped.

Comment: Another similar question answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020343/spark-dataframe-access-of-previous-calculated-row

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate all columns using good ol' SQL:

```
SELECT userID min(timestamp), max(timestamp), collect_list(actions)
FROM df GROUP BY userID
```

or Dataset API:

```
df.groupBy("userID").agg(
    min("timestamp") as "startTime",
    max("timestamp") as "endTime",
    collect_list("actions") as "actions")
```

Comment: Sadly that would result in the following rows:  

`[(u1      100        241      [edit1, edit2, edit3, edit6, edit7]),
(u2      143        158      [edit4, edit5] )]`  

and would not maintain separate sessions for the same user.

u1 needs to have 2 rows which represent the two sessions.