# Spark SQL window function look ahead and complex function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have the following data:

```
+-----+----+-----+
|event|t   |type |
+-----+----+-----+
| A   |20  | 1   |
| A   |40  | 1   |
| B   |10  | 1   |
| B   |20  | 1   |
| B   |120 | 1   |
| B   |140 | 1   |
| B   |320 | 1   |
| B   |340 | 1   |
| B   |360 | 7   |
| B   |380 | 1   |
+-----+-----+----+
```

And what I want is something like this:

```
+-----+----+----+
|event|t   |grp |
+-----+----+----+
| A   |20  |1   |
| A   |40  |1   |
| B   |10  |2   |
| B   |20  |2   |
| B   |120 |3   |
| B   |140 |3   |
| B   |320 |4   |
| B   |340 |4   |
| B   |380 |5   |
+-----+----+----+
```

Rules:

1. Group all Values together that are at least 50ms away from each other. (column t) and belongs to the same event.
2. When a row of type 7 appears take a cut too and remove this row. (see last row)

The first rule I can achieve with the answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition):

Code:

```
val windowSpec= Window.partitionBy("event").orderBy("t")

 val newSession =  (coalesce(
  ($"t" - lag($"t", 1).over(windowSpec)),
  lit(0)
) > 50).cast("bigint")

val sessionized = df.withColumn("session", sum(newSession).over(userWindow))
```

I have to say I can't figure it out how it works and don't know how to modify it so that rule 2 also works... 
Hope someone can give me some useful hints.

What I tried:

```
val newSession =  (coalesce(
  ($"t" - lag($"t", 1).over(windowSpec)),
  lit(0)
) > 50 || lead($"type",1).over(windowSpec) =!= 7 ).cast("bigint")
```

But only an error occurred: "Must follow method; cannot follow `org.apache.spark.sql.Column val grp = (coalesce(`

Comment: if your window function is working then just filter out rows with type == 7 before applying your window function

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I don't think this works, because if you remove this first, you cannot "cut" anymore

Comment: Why is `grp` for event B starting at 2 in your expected result?

Comment: a mistake of me but thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
val newSession =  (coalesce(
  ($"t" - lag($"t", 1).over(win)),
  lit(0)
) > 50 
  or $"type"===7) // also start new group in this case
 .cast("bigint")

df.withColumn("session", sum(newSession).over(win))
.where($"type"=!=7) // remove these rows
.orderBy($"event",$"t")
.show
```

gives:

```
+-----+---+----+-------+
|event|  t|type|session|
+-----+---+----+-------+
|    A| 20|   1|      0|
|    A| 40|   1|      0|
|    B| 10|   1|      0|
|    B| 20|   1|      0|
|    B|120|   1|      1|
|    B|140|   1|      1|
|    B|320|   1|      2|
|    B|340|   1|      2|
|    B|380|   1|      3|
+-----+---+----+-------+
```