# Filtering a spark DataFrame down to updates only

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` in Spark consisting of columns for id, date, and a number of properties (x, y, z, say). Unfortunately the DataFrame is very large. Fortunately, most of the records are "no-change" records, in which the id, x, y, and z are the same, and only the date changes. For example

```
| date     | id | x |
| -------- | -- | - |
| 20150101 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150102 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150103 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150104 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150105 | 1  | 2 |
| 20150106 | 1  | 2 |
| 20150107 | 1  | 2 |
| 20150108 | 1  | 2 |
```

could be reduced to

```
| date     | id | x |
| -------- | -- | - |
| 20150101 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150105 | 1  | 2 |
```

I originally thought that this function would do what I wanted

```
def filterToUpdates (df : DataFrame) = {
  val colsData = df.column.filter(x => (x != "id" && x != "date"))
  val window = Window.partitionBy(colsData).orderBy($"date".asc)
  df.withColumn("row_num", row_number.over(window)).
    select($"row_num" === 1).drop("row_num")
```

But that fails in the case when I have my data columns change, and then change back.

e.g.

```
| date     | id | x |
| -------- | -- | - |
| 20150101 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150102 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150103 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150104 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150105 | 1  | 2 |
| 20150106 | 1  | 2 |
| 20150107 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150108 | 1  | 1 |
```

would be transformed to

```
| date     | id | x |
| -------- | -- | - |
| 20150101 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150105 | 1  | 2 |
```

instead of what I want:

```
| date     | id | x |
| -------- | -- | - |
| 20150101 | 1  | 1 |
| 20150105 | 1  | 2 |
| 20150107 | 1  | 1 |
```

This wouldn't be a difficult task in procedural code that got handed the records for row in order (partitioned by id and ordered by date), but I just can't see how to phrase it as a spark computation.

**Note:** this differs from [Spark SQL window function with complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition). I'm looking to filter out rows that differ from previous rows, which is an additional thing that could be done *after* the construction of the `became_inactive` column in that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL window function with complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use `lag`. Window

```scala
val window = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"date".asc)
```

Column

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, lag, lit}

val keep = coalesce(lag($"x", 1).over(window) =!= $"x", lit(true))

df.withColumn("keep", keep).where($"keep").drop("keep").show

// +--------+---+---+
// |    date| id|  x|
// +--------+---+---+
// |20150101|  1|  1|
// |20150105|  1|  2|
// |20150107|  1|  1|
// +--------+---+---+
```

Comment: This works for the example I showed where I have a single 'data' variable `x` that I want to watch for changes in. But what about the case where I have multiple columns (`x1`, `x2`, ..., `xn`, say), and I only know what those columns are called (and how many there are) from a `Seq[String]`. The problem in that case is that `lag` is not variadic. Should I be making a `Seq[Column]` of different versions of `"keep"`, and then do fold the thread `df` through the sequnce of columns and filter for them?

Comment: You'll need something like `val keep  = cols.map(x => coalesce(lag(x, 1).over(window) =!= x, lit(true))).reduce(_ | _)`