# Scala - Generate all combinations (with order) and count

Tags: scala

In Scala,
I have a sequence `val test : Seq[String] = Seq("table","bag","chair","chair")`

I want to generate all the combinations of the above sequence, with order being important, and also count the times that combination is present in the sequence.
i.e. `(table,bag,1), (table,chair,2), (bag,table,1), (bag,chair,2), (chair,table,1), (chair,bag,2)`.

Also, I don't need to consider the combination of same element i.e. `(chair,chair)` has to be ignored.
How could I do this?

Comment: you can use subsets method for this purpose and then filter which has length 2.

Comment: Why is `(bag,chair,2)` but `(chair,bag,1)`? If "chair" is in the sequence twice shouldn't every combination with "chair" come up with 2?

Comment: Yeah, it is better to consider `(chair,bag,2)`

Comment: @RamanMishra if I use subset, then `(table, bag)` and `(bag,table)` becomes same, but I want to keep it different

Comment: @JeetBanerjee table, chair, 2 and chair, table, 1 why?

Comment: So question, what is the result you want for `val seq = Seq("One", "One", "Two", "Two")`? `List((One,Two,4), (Two,One,4))`?

Comment: Also what is the result that you want for `Seq("One", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Three")`? Is it `List((One,Two,4), (One,Three,1), (Two,Three,4), (Three,Two,4), (Two,One,4), (Three,One,1))`?

Comment: @jeet.. I have the answer for the other question that you posted today..53281994/spark-scala-variable-window-range-over-a-dataframe it was closed by community.. please raise a new question and I'll share the answer

Comment: @stack0114106 hey thanks, but I found the answer to that question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition) question was similar and I understood the proper approach to use spark sql window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about it, the count for any combination (pairing) is the count of the 1st element times the count of the 2nd element.

```
val ws = Seq("table","bag","chair","chair")
val count = ws.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
val result = ws.distinct.combinations(2).flatMap{ case Seq(a,b) =>
    val comboCount = count(a) * count(b)
    Seq((a,b,comboCount), (b,a,comboCount))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
val ans: Seq[(String, String)] = for {
    a <- test
    b <- test
    if a != b
  } yield {
      (a, b)
  }

    val result: Iterator[(String, String, Int)] = ans.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).toIterator.map{
    case ((key, value), frequency)=> (key, value, frequency)
  }

  result1.foreach(println)
```

**output**

```
(bag,table,1)
(table,chair,2)
(chair,table,2)
(chair,bag,2)
(bag,chair,2)
(table,bag,1)
```