# spark group and reduce based on adjacent rows as well as single row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below and want to reduce them by combining adjacent rowa i.e previous.close = current.open

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Ray","2018-09-01","2018-09-10"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-10","2018-09-15"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-16","2018-09-18"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-21","2018-09-27"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-27","2018-09-30"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-21","2018-09-23"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-24","2018-09-28"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-28","2018-09-30"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-05","2018-10-09"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-11","2018-10-15"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-15","2018-09-20")
)
```

The required output is below:

```
  (("Ray","2018-09-01","2018-09-15"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-16","2018-09-18"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-21","2018-09-30"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-21","2018-09-23"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-24","2018-09-30"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-05","2018-10-09"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-11","2018-10-20"))
```

So, far, I'm able to condense the adjacent rows by using the below DF() solution.

```
df.alias("t1").join(df.alias("t2"),$"t1.name" === $"t2.name" and $"t1.close"=== $"t2.open" )
  .select("t1.name","t1.open","t2.close")
  .distinct.show(false) 

|name |open      |close     |
+-----+----------+----------+
|Scott|2018-09-24|2018-09-30|
|Scott|2018-10-11|2018-09-20|
|Ray  |2018-09-01|2018-09-15|
|Ray  |2018-09-21|2018-09-30|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

I'm trying to use similar style to get single rows by giving $"t1.close"=!= $"t2.open" and then doing a union of both to get the final result. But I get unwanted rows, which I'm not able to filter correctly. How to achieve this?.

This post is not same as  [Spark SQL window function with complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition) where it calculates additional date column as a new column.

Comment: Not exactly.. if you see, the dates are in sorted order within each name key. When previous close is equal to current open, then just combine them. Otherwise, the standalone row should be included in the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL window function with complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

1. Create new column `temp1` with `null` value if current `open` equals previous `close`; otherwise value of current `open`
2. Create another column `temp2` that backfills `null`s in `temp1` with the `last` non-null value
3. Group resulting dataset by (`name`, `temp2`) to generate the contiguous date ranges

I've revised your sample data to cover cases of contiguous date range over 2+ rows.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  ("Ray","2018-09-01","2018-09-10"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-10","2018-09-15"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-16","2018-09-18"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-21","2018-09-27"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-27","2018-09-30"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-21","2018-09-23"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-23","2018-09-28"),  // <-- Revised
  ("Scott","2018-09-28","2018-09-30"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-05","2018-10-09"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-11","2018-10-15"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-15","2018-10-20")
).toDF("name", "open", "close")

val win = Window.partitionBy($"name").orderBy("open", "close")

val df2 = df.
  withColumn("temp1", when(
    row_number.over(win) === 1 || lag($"close", 1).over(win) =!= $"open", $"open")
  ).
  withColumn("temp2", last($"temp1", ignoreNulls=true).over(
    win.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
  ))

df2.show
// +-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
// | name|      open|     close|     temp1|     temp2|
// +-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
// |Scott|2018-09-21|2018-09-23|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|
// |Scott|2018-09-23|2018-09-28|      null|2018-09-21|
// |Scott|2018-09-28|2018-09-30|      null|2018-09-21|
// |Scott|2018-10-05|2018-10-09|2018-10-05|2018-10-05|
// |Scott|2018-10-11|2018-10-15|2018-10-11|2018-10-11|
// |Scott|2018-10-15|2018-10-20|      null|2018-10-11|
// |  Ray|2018-09-01|2018-09-10|2018-09-01|2018-09-01|
// |  Ray|2018-09-10|2018-09-15|      null|2018-09-01|
// |  Ray|2018-09-16|2018-09-18|2018-09-16|2018-09-16|
// |  Ray|2018-09-21|2018-09-27|2018-09-21|2018-09-21|
// |  Ray|2018-09-27|2018-09-30|      null|2018-09-21|
// +-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The above shows result of step `1` and `2` with `temp2` holding the value of the earliest `open` of the corresponding contiguous date range.  Step `3` uses `max` to get the latest `close` of the date range:

```
df2.
  groupBy($"name", $"temp2".as("open")).agg(max($"close").as("close")).
  show
// +-----+----------+----------+
// |name |open      |close     |
// +-----+----------+----------+
// |Scott|2018-09-21|2018-09-30|
// |Scott|2018-10-05|2018-10-09|
// |Scott|2018-10-11|2018-10-20|
// |Ray  |2018-09-01|2018-09-15|
// |Ray  |2018-09-16|2018-09-18|
// |Ray  |2018-09-21|2018-09-30|
// +-----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: hey..cool.. it works on the training dataset.. let me check on the bigger one and accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: the code is now tested :-)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, datediff, lag, lit, min, sum}

val df = Seq(
  ("Ray","2018-09-01","2018-09-10"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-10","2018-09-15"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-16","2018-09-18"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-21","2018-09-27"),
  ("Ray","2018-09-27","2018-09-30"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-21","2018-09-23"),
  ("Scott","2018-09-23","2018-09-28"),  // <-- Revised
  ("Scott","2018-09-28","2018-09-30"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-05","2018-10-09"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-11","2018-10-15"),
  ("Scott","2018-10-15","2018-10-20")
).toDF("name", "open", "close")

val window = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy($"open").rowsBetween(-1, Window.currentRow) //<- only compare the dates of a certain name, and for each row look also look at the previous one

df.select(
  $"name", $"open", $"close",
  min($"close").over(window) as "closeBefore_tmp"//<- get the smaller close value (that of the previous entry) 
)
.withColumn("closeBefore", when($"closeBefore_tmp" === $"close", null).otherwise($"closeBefore_tmp")) //<- in this case there was no previous row: its the first for this user, so set closeBefore to null
.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
```

Now you can `compare` open and `closeBefore`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I have just written down things while sitting in the subway. Thats why I noted down, that there might be errors. I hope you can execute the code now directly. :-)