# Spark marking duplicate user login within 24 hour after first login

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a dataset with users and login time. I need to mark duplicate if there is/additional logins within 24 hour period AFTER First login. Activity window opens with user login. For example,  here is sample data set

```
user    login
-----------------------------
user1   12/1/19 8:00
user1   12/1/19 10:00
user1   12/1/19 23:00
user1   12/2/19 7:00
user1   12/2/19 8:00
user1   12/2/19 10:00
user1   12/3/19 23:00
user1   12/4/19 7:00
user2   12/4/19 8:00
user2   12/5/19 5:00
user2   12/6/19 0:00
```

Expected result

```
user    login           Duplicate
---------------------------------
user1   12/1/19 8:00    N    this is first login for user1 - 24 hour window opens here
user1   12/1/19 10:00   Y    since this is within 24 hours 
user1   12/1/19 23:00   Y   
user1   12/2/19 7:00    Y
user1   12/2/19 8:00    Y
user1   12/2/19 10:00   N   This activity time is greater than (previous window open + 24 hrs). previous window closes and second window opens here
user1   12/3/19 23:00   N
user1   12/4/19 7:00    Y
user2   12/4/19 8:00    N
user2   12/5/19 5:00    Y
user2   12/6/19 0:00    N
```

I looked  [Spark SQL window function with complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition) but this solution won't work if user logins are at fixed interval let's say every 18 hours.

Here is another example (if solution considers only first activity to calculate 24 hr window, it will give incorrect result(Non-duplicate) for record # 7 below)

```
user1   12/1/19 8:00    N    this is first login for user1 - 24 hour window opens here
user1   12/1/19 10:00   Y    since this is within 24 hours 
user1   12/1/19 23:00   Y   
user1   12/2/19 7:00    Y
user1   12/2/19 8:00    Y
user1   12/2/19 10:00   N  This activity time is greater than (previous window open + 24 hrs). previous window closes and second window opens here
**user1   12/3/19 09:00 N**
user1   12/3/19 23:00   N
user1   12/4/19 7:00    Y
user2   12/4/19 8:00    N
user2   12/5/19 5:00    Y
user2   12/6/19 0:00    N
```

Comment: shouldnt second last row in Duplicate column be Y, and last row be N?

Comment: U r right @MohammadMurtazaHashmi . Edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built-in Spark functions that can successively identify the start of the next 24-hour session (or any given time period) based on where the previous session ends in a dynamic fashion.  One approach to handle such requirement is through a UDF that leverages Scala's `fold` function:

```
def dupeFlags(tLimit: Long) = udf{ (logins: Seq[String], tsDiffs: Seq[Long]) =>
  val flags = tsDiffs.foldLeft( (List[String](), 0L) ){ case ((flags, tsAcc), ts) =>
    if (ts == 0 || tsAcc + ts > tLimit)
      ("N" :: flags, 0L)
    else
      ("Y" :: flags, tsAcc + ts)
  }._1.reverse
  logins zip flags
}
```

The UDF takes a list of `time-diff` (in seconds between current and previous rows) to be processed.  Note that the accumulator for `foldLeft` in the UDF is a Tuple of (flags, tsAcc), where:

- `flags` is the list of duplicate-flags to be returned
- `tsAcc` is for carrying over the conditionally cumulating timestamp value to the next iteration

Also note that the list of `login-date` is only "passed thru" in order to be included in the final dataset.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("user1", "12/1/19 8:00"),
  ("user1", "12/1/19 10:00"),
  ("user1", "12/1/19 23:00"),
  ("user1", "12/2/19 7:00"),
  ("user1", "12/2/19 8:00"),
  ("user1", "12/2/19 10:00"),
  ("user1", "12/3/19 9:00"),
  ("user1", "12/3/19 23:00"),
  ("user1", "12/4/19 7:00"),
  ("user2", "12/4/19 8:00"),
  ("user2", "12/5/19 5:00"),
  ("user2", "12/6/19 0:00")
).toDF("user", "login")
```

Using `groupBy/collect_list`, the list of `time-diff` along with `login-date` list are fed to the UDF to generate the wanted duplicate-flags, which then get flattened using `explode`:

```
val win1 = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("ts")

df.
  withColumn("ts", unix_timestamp(to_timestamp($"login", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"))).
  withColumn("tsPrev", coalesce(lag($"ts", 1).over(win1), $"ts")).
  groupBy("user").agg(collect_list($"login").as("logins"), collect_list($"ts" - $"tsPrev").as("tsDiffs")).
  withColumn("tuple", explode(dupeFlags(60 * 60 * 24L)($"logins", $"tsDiffs"))).
  select($"user", $"tuple._1".as("login"), $"tuple._2".as("duplicate")).
  show
// +-----+-------------+---------+
// | user|        login|duplicate|
// +-----+-------------+---------+
// |user1| 12/1/19 8:00|        N|
// |user1|12/1/19 10:00|        Y|
// |user1|12/1/19 23:00|        Y|
// |user1| 12/2/19 7:00|        Y|
// |user1| 12/2/19 8:00|        Y|
// |user1|12/2/19 10:00|        N|
// |user1| 12/3/19 9:00|        Y|
// |user1|12/3/19 23:00|        N|
// |user1| 12/4/19 7:00|        Y|
// |user2| 12/4/19 8:00|        N|
// |user2| 12/5/19 5:00|        Y|
// |user2| 12/6/19 0:00|        N|
// +-----+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Without udf, I cannot figure out the way to achieve this. The only way is the iteration as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

**Python:** Here is the conversion of my scala code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lag, unix_timestamp, to_timestamp, lit, when, row_number, first
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("user", "index").orderBy("login")
df2 = df.withColumn("login", to_timestamp(col("login"), "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"))

df2.join(df2.groupBy("user").agg(first("login").alias("firstLogin")), "user", "left") \
   .withColumn("index", ((unix_timestamp(col("login")) - unix_timestamp(col("firstLogin"))) / 86400).cast("int")) \
   .withColumn("Duplicate", when(row_number().over(w) == 1, lit("N")).otherwise(lit("Y"))) \
   .orderBy("user", "login") \
   .show(20)
```

**Scala:** You can use `lag` function with the time difference index column as I made,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("user", "index").orderBy("login")
val df2 = df.withColumn("login", to_timestamp($"login", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"))

df2.join(df2.groupBy("user").agg(first("login").as("firstLogin")), Seq("user"), "left")
   .withColumn("index", ((unix_timestamp(col("login")) - unix_timestamp(col("firstLogin"))) / 86400).cast("int"))
   .withColumn("Duplicate", when(row_number.over(w) === 1, lit("N")).otherwise(lit("Y")))
   .orderBy("user", "login")

   .show
```

The result is:

```
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+---------+
| user|              login|         firstLogin|index|Duplicate|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+---------+
|user1|2019-12-01 08:00:00|2019-12-01 08:00:00|    0|        N|
|user1|2019-12-01 10:00:00|2019-12-01 08:00:00|    0|        Y|
|user1|2019-12-01 23:00:00|2019-12-01 08:00:00|    0|        Y|
|user1|2019-12-02 07:00:00|2019-12-01 08:00:00|    0|        Y|
|user1|2019-12-02 08:00:00|2019-12-01 08:00:00|    1|        N|
|user1|2019-12-02 10:00:00|2019-12-01 08:00:00|    1|        Y|
|user1|2019-12-03 23:00:00|2019-12-01 08:00:00|    2|        N|
|user1|2019-12-04 07:00:00|2019-12-01 08:00:00|    2|        Y|
|user2|2019-12-04 08:00:00|2019-12-04 08:00:00|    0|        N|
|user2|2019-12-05 05:00:00|2019-12-04 08:00:00|    0|        Y|
|user2|2019-12-06 00:00:00|2019-12-04 08:00:00|    1|        N|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, this solution has the same problem as the [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448564/spark-sql-window-function-with-complex-condition . This is comparing with previous activity and doesn't consider start of login window . For ex, if I add between 5th and 6th row [code] user1|2019-12-02 08:01:0 [code]. this activity should be a new window start but it will be marked duplicate with above code. @Lamanus

Comment: Now, is this reasonable?

Comment: @Lamanus I think solution considers first login time. In my view it will produce same result as before . I have added another example scenario . Record#7 in third dataset might produce incorrect result and that's my issue here.

Comment: I am still thinking... So difficult :)

Comment: I really appreciate help @Lamanus . Agree it's difficult without iteration or cache per user entry and that requires UDF . I will see what I can do about it.