# Pyspark Grouped Map Pandas UDF - Does it keep the order of the rows in the group?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm using pandas_udf to create a Grouped Map (split-apply-combine pattern) UDF in pyspark and I need to know if the order of the rows is keeped when passed to the UDF (my transformation depends on the order of the rows for each group).

Comment: i think it will keep whatever order u send to it for each group.check this out to make sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346471/partition-by-24-hours-and-aggregate-using-pyspark-or-panda/61374536#61374536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No!

Pyspark groupby triggers a shuffle and this shuffle is **not guaranteed** to preserve any previously existing order. To process your data in an order in a Grouped Map, sort the dataset at the the top of the UDF.

```
@pandas_udf(my_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_udf(key_group):
    # Key group is not guaranteed to be ordered by key2 at this point!!
    key_group = key_group.sort_values("key2")
    # Now it's ordered by key2 and I can do my processing
    ...
    return my_processed_data

df.orderBy("key1", "key2").groupBy("key1").apply(my_udf)
```